# How can I find CRLB for an integer valued Maximum Likelihood Estimator?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

Reference: [How to find Maximum Likelihood estimates of an *integer* parameter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412670/how-to-find-maximum-likelihood-estimates-of-an-integer-parameter)

Extending the above question, how to find the Fisher information and hence CRLB for the integer-valued Estimator using second forward difference operator.

Comment: Related, but still unanswered, question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126148/generalization-of-fisher-information-for-a-discrete-parameter

Comment: Thanks kjetil b halvorsen for the info